# Dynamic add views in layout Vs ListView with respect to performance

Tags: android

Getting set of data from server, that need to display on UI.

Currently i am checking length of data in JSONArray then creating dynamic view and displaying data on UI.

But same thing i can do with Custom List view as well.

Please suggest best way to deal with this, performance wise which option would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small set of data you should use ListView(if you have parsed json in listview already). But, I would recommend you use RecyclerView from now on as it has various advantages over ListView and even google experts recommend it.

Search for RecyclerView on google and you will know the benefits. For example purpose to get kick start visit : [RecyclerView example](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

From now on get used to it. It is very helpful also, take a look at some of the 3rd part libraries such as Volley and Retrofit.

Best of Luck!